# Finding the minimal polynomial of Linear transformation $T(A) =A-A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to find the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of T but I found that for certain matrix $A$ it is never $0$.

The transformation is $T:M_{\leq n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_{\leq n}(\mathbb{C})$ where $T(A)=A-A^t$

Comment: Hint: Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of T and show that T is diagonalizable by showing that the vector space is the sum of T's eigenspaces. From there, the minimal and characteristic polynomials are easy.

Comment: What is $M_{\le n}({\bf C})$? Square matrices of order at most $n$? That's not a vector space – you can't add a $2\times2$ matrix to a $3\times3$ matrix. If you mean the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices, that space has a basis, each of whose elements is either symmetric or skew-symmetric, and from there you can follow the advice from @Anon.

Comment: It might help if you think of $A$ as the sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices.  What does $T$ do to each of these kinds of matrices?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It might be $\oplus_{k=0}^n M_k(\mathbb{C})$, i.e. formal direct sums of square matrices of size at most $n$. Never seen this notation though.

Comment: Please, Itay, what do you mean by $M_{\le n}({\bf C})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^2(A)=(A-A^t)-(A-A^t)^t=(A-A^t)-(A^t-A)=2(A-A^t)=2T(A)$ for all $A$.

So $T^2-2T=0$; the minimum polynomial is $p(x)=x(x-2)$.

The minimum polynomial always divides and has the same roots as the characteristic polynomial, so the characteristic polynomial is in the form $q(x)=x^{d_1}(x-2)^{d_2}$ for $d_1,d_2 >0$. Our goal is to find the $d_i$'s.

A sufficient condition for diagonalizability is that the minimum polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors, so $T$ is diagonalizable. A necessary condition of diagonalizability is that the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometric multiplicity for each associated eigenspace-- this will help us find the $d_i$'s.

The zero-eigenspace consists of vectors $A$ such that $TA=0A$, i.e. $(A-A^t)=0 \implies A=A^t$ (the set of $n \times n$ skew-matrices). One can simply count the dimensions needed-- there are $n^2$ dimensions for the full space and dependencies on the lower triangular-- so $1$ for the first column, $2$ for the second column, etc., up to $n$ for the $n^{\text{th}}$ column, a total of $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Since the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces must equal the dimension of the full space, we know the two-eigenspace has dimension $n^2-\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$. So the characteristic polynomial is $q(x)=x^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}(x-2)^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$.

Comment: Are you interpreting $M_{\le n}$ as $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yes, is that off?

Comment: I don't know. I asked OP, who hasn't answered. But why would OP include the $\le$ symbol in the notation, if what's at issue is matrices that are exactly $n\times n$?